# hive query inside shell script

Tags: shell, hive

I want to run the hive query inside the shell script. I want to exit shell script and throw error if my hive query fails. 
Right now, even if my hive query fails, the next steps are getting executed. can someone help with this:

val=`hive -e "
select col1 from table_name;"` 
(assuming the table has only one row)

echo "don't run if hive fails"

Comment: how about using an oozie workflow for hive command execution and handling failures - https://gist.github.com/tmusabbir/7019600

Answer (score 1):

```
hive -e "select col1 from table_name"

if test $? -ne 0
then 
    exit 1
fi
```